# Does it make sense to use Retire.js library for vulnerabilities scanning or should it be enough to simply run npm audit

Tags: node.js, reactjs, security, npm-audit

I'm trying add some tools to my application for security scanning and I came across this tool [Retire.js](https://retirejs.github.io/retire.js/)

I wasn't sure whether it makes sense to add it to my application, since from briefly reading documentation for both Retire.js and npm audit I got a feeling that it does the same analysis. Would this be correct? And if no, would it be recommended to use Retire.js on top of regularly running npm audit?

Stack:

- Frontend: React app built with Create-React-App
- Backend: Node.JS + Express app